# How does emergent oscillation appear in this animation of concentric circles?

Tags: graphing-functions, periodic-functions

I made this animation and I barely understand it. http://bl.ocks.org/tophtucker/500d2a010105cfcc87db

It's a bunch of concentric circles with exclusion compositing. The radius of the `i`th circle oscillates with `amplitude * Math.sin(t/speed + (t/10000)*i)`, where `amplitude` and `speed` are fixed parameters (changed by mouse movements) and where `t` is the number of milliseconds since you loaded the page. E.g., for `amplitude = 5` and `speed = 500`, the radius of circle `i` at time `t` oscillates with period `(20000π)/(20+i)` in `t`, [says WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5*sin%28t%2F500+%2B+%28t%2F10000%29*i%29&a=i_Variable).

Things periodically seem sync up in cool ways, I guess when the derivative with respect to `i` is small? Because then the concentric circles oscillate in phase?